# File opening error in ffmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-encoding

i am using ffmpeg for video merge. as it contains 3-4 steps. in one step in which i wants to extract audio part from multiple videos and get single merged audio. i am facing error:

```
[avs @ 6c370838 JAVIFileOpen faild with error - 2147221164E:\mypath\bin\debug\videos\video.avs: Error while opening file
```

i am using below command (using c#) to get audio part: <<<>>>

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "E:\mypath\bin\Debug\Videos\video.avs" -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 41000 -ab 64k -y -ac 2 "E:\mypath\bin\Debug\Videos\audio.wav"
```

and the text in video.avs is :

```
video = UnalignedSplice(DirectShowSource("bumper.wmv", fps = 25, Convertfps = true), DirectShowSource("video.wmv", fps = 25, Convertfps = true, audio = false), DirectShowSource("trailer.wmv", fps = 25, Convertfps =true))
audio = DirectShowSource("video.wmv", video = false)
Clip = AudioDub(video, audio)
DelayAudio(Clip, +1)
```

I am using below code to write video.avs file:

```
StreamWriter writer2 = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\\Videos\\videoPart.avs");
                        writer2.WriteLine("UnalignedSplice(DirectShowSource(\"" + "bumper.wmv" + "\", fps = 25, Convertfps = true),"
                        + " DirectShowSource(\"" + "video.wmv" + "\", fps = 25, Convertfps = true, audio = false),"
                        + " DirectShowSource(\"" + "trailer.wmv" + "\", fps = 25, Convertfps =true))");
                        writer2.Close();
```

Please help me.

Comment: Hey - I am no expert here. May sound obvious, but can FFMPEG actually read the file? Are the perms set correctly?

Comment: @Christopher: yes you are right ffmpeg not read file but we can do it by using "Avisynth".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the answer.
i was getting this error because i am using .avs files which cannot be read by ffmpeg. to make ffmpeg to use .avs file we will have to install "Avisynth".

you can download "Avisynth" from : http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Avisynth